# Mongoose error no geo indices for geoNear

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Originally I had it divided up into a schemas but have since removed them and simply nested them inside of my overall document. I have tried putting indexes on everything and removing them from coordinates to location. I am thinking there could be an issue because the points are nested. When I run get Indexes it shows that there is an index on location.point.
No matter what it keeps saying that they are no indexes. I am new to MERN. I am not sure what I am missing here. How do I fix this error so that GeoNear finds the index in the nested document. As you can see I am using the dot notation and have added the index.

````
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  published: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
  },
  placeType: placeTypeSchema,
  capacity: {
    maxGuestSize: Number,
    rooms: Number
  },
  bathrooms: Number,
  location: {
    streetAddress: String,
    suite: String,
    country: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: String,
    point: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: "Point",
        index: '2dsphere'
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
        //index: '2dsphere'
      }
    }
  },
  amenities: {
    regular: [String],
    safety: [String]
  },
  sharedSpaces: [String],
  imageUrl: String,
  description: {
    description: String,
    hostAvailablity: String,
    spaceDetails: String,
    neighborhood: String,
    transportation: String
  },
  title: String,
  mobileNumber: String,
  houseRules: houseRulesSchema,
  preference: {
    rentedLocationBefore: Boolean,
    howOftenGuests: String
  },
  notice: {
    guestNoticeTime: Number,
    checkInTime: Date
  },
  advance: Number,
  lengthOfStay: {
    min: Number,
    max: Number
  },
  price: {
    basePrice: Number,
    minPrice: Number,
    maxPrice: Number
  }
});

SpotSchema.index({"location.point": "2dsphere"});


Spot = mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema);
module.exports = Spot; ```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hpSE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gevTo.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference. I fixed it by removing the nesting and making the document flatter and just adding another key separate from the location key on the same access level. Everything works fine now.

```
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  published: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
  },
  placeType: placeTypeSchema,
  capacity: {
    maxGuestSize: Number,
    rooms: Number
  },
  bathrooms: Number,
  location: {
    streetAddress: String,
    suite: String,
    country: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: String,
  },
  precise: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "Point"
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      default: [-97.1251805, 33.088988]
      //index: '2dsphere'
    }
  },
  amenities: {
    regular: [String],
    safety: [String]
  },
  sharedSpaces: [String],
  imageUrl: String,
  description: {
    description: String,
    hostAvailablity: String,
    spaceDetails: String,
    neighborhood: String,
    transportation: String
  },
  title: String,
  mobileNumber: String,
  houseRules: houseRulesSchema,
  preference: {
    rentedLocationBefore: Boolean,
    howOftenGuests: String
  },
  notice: {
    guestNoticeTime: Number,
    checkInTime: Date
  },
  advance: Number,
  lengthOfStay: {
    min: Number,
    max: Number
  },
  price: {
    basePrice: Number,
    minPrice: Number,
    maxPrice: Number
  }
});

SpotSchema.index({"precise": "2dsphere"});


Spot = mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema);
module.exports = Spot;
```